# Random index generator in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11

I have a training dataset from which I want to draw samples in a random fashion such that all samples are used before getting randomly shuffled again. For this reason I implemented a simple random index generator.

For a dataset of 10 samples, the output looks something like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
4 3 7 8 0 5 2 1 6 9 
0 5 7 8 4 3 9 2 1 6 
5 7 6 3 8 4 2 0 1 9 
4 6 0 2 8 1 3 9 5 7 
4 0 5 1 7 9 6 2 8 3 
3 8 5 6 1 7 2 4 0 9 
0 4 6 2 9 5 8 3 1 7 
1 3 6 8 2 7 5 9 0 4 
5 1 7 9 8 0 6 4 2 3
```

I would appreciate advice especially in the following areas:

- Code style (readability, naming conventions, etc...)
- Class design
- Efficiency (how to avoid unnecessary complexity)
- Reinventing the wheel (does the STL offer functionality that I should use?)
- Are there perhaps bugs that I am not seeing right now?

Please be as hard as possible with this implementation and give me constructive feedback.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "random_index.hpp"

int main() {
    unsigned int size = 10;
    RandomIndex rand_idx(size);

    unsigned int n = 0;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<100; ++i, ++n) {
        std::cout << rand_idx.get_index() << ' ';
        if ((n+1) % size == 0) {
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**random_index.cpp**

```
#include "random_index.hpp"

RandomIndex::RandomIndex(unsigned int _size) {
    size = _size;
    index.resize(_size, 0);
    std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);
}

unsigned int RandomIndex::get_index() {
    if (counter < size) {
        return index[counter++];
    } else {
        counter = 0;
        std::random_shuffle(index.begin(), index.end());
        return index[counter++];
    }
}
```

**random_index.hpp**

```
#ifndef RANDOM_INDEX_H
#define RANDOM_INDEX_H

#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

class RandomIndex {
    
    public:
        RandomIndex(unsigned int _size);
        unsigned int get_index();
    
    private:
        unsigned int size;
        unsigned int counter = 0;
        std::vector<unsigned int> index;

};

#endif
```

I compiled the code using the following command:

```
g++ -O -Wall main.cpp random_index.cpp
```

Comment: You might want to use [`std::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) instead.

Answer (score 3):

### Overview

Your code produces the exact same set of samples each time you `random_shuffle`. So the output is always

```cpp
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
4 3 7 8 0 5 2 1 6 9 
0 5 7 8 4 3 9 2 1 6 
5 7 6 3 8 4 2 0 1 9 
4 6 0 2 8 1 3 9 5 7 
4 0 5 1 7 9 6 2 8 3 
3 8 5 6 1 7 2 4 0 9 
0 4 6 2 9 5 8 3 1 7 
1 3 6 8 2 7 5 9 0 4 
5 1 7 9 8 0 6 4 2 3
```

---

You should initialize the [seed](https://cutt.ly/gjn8NAx). You do that before you call `random_shuffle`. If you do not do that it will give the same result each time since it relies on the seed.

You can fix that by calling `std::srand` in the beginning.

```cpp
int main() {
    std::srand(std::time(0));
}
```

Now you can see the difference in the output

```cpp
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 2 8 3 6 4 0 7 1 5
8 9 4 6 7 2 1 5 0 3
4 6 0 2 3 1 5 8 9 7
2 3 0 1 6 8 9 5 7 4
8 9 6 5 2 1 3 7 4 0
9 3 2 8 6 7 5 0 4 1
8 1 2 5 9 6 4 3 0 7
7 1 4 6 8 9 3 0 5 2
3 1 9 4 2 7 6 0 5 8
```

But the top row still will always be the same. The problem lies here

```cpp
RandomIndex::RandomIndex(unsigned int _size) {
    size = _size;
    index.resize(_size, 0);
    std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);
}
```

`iota` will always will it starting with `0` and incrementing it will it reaches `index.end()`. `get_index` will only shuffle the container after the first row since that's when `counter < size` evaluates to false.

To fix that you can also shuffle in the beginning, when you construct the vector.

---

### Use `std::shuffle`

[`random_shuffle` has been deprecated](https://meetingcpp.com/blog/items/stdrandom_shuffle-is-deprecated.html). Use `shuffle`  with a random number generator so that your code can compile on the later c++ versions.

---

### Avoid using `_` as a prefix for your variables

There are some [naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier#:%7E:text=You%20should%20avoid%20using%20one,by%20a%20lower%2Dcase%20letter.) you need to follow when it comes to underscores to avoid collisions. Moreover, it just looks ugly. To initialize `size` in your class constructor you are better off using [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

```cpp
RandomIndex::RandomIndex(unsigned int size)
    : size(size)  {

 //...
}
```

---

### use an `array` with a fixed size over vector

In your class `size` is a value that is never going to change. If you plan on keeping it that way you can, use `std::array` here with a template so you can have a fixed size. This will avoid all the resizing and heap fiddling resulting in faster execution. `std::shuffle` will work the same way it does with `vector` thanks to the way STL is designed.

```cpp
template < size_t s >
class RandomIndex {
   //...

private:
    std::array < uint32_t, s > index;
   
};
```